# How can I troubleshoot Macbook pro 13 with touch bar model 2017 that won’t start?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, power

I took my Mac on vacation where it was working fine. Upon return, I opened it up and nothing;  no start or any sound. I tried all the tricks of soft keys but nothing.

I don't understand what went wrong. It was properly shut down before I boarded a flight. I always hand carried it;  never dropped or had any liquid spillage.

I am totally confused as to what could have happened to it.  The warranty expired in November 2018.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The very first thing I would check is to see if it is fully charged.  Your charger may have failed and is no longer charging/powering your MBP.

Comment: When I shutdown it was 100% charged before boarding a flight. I have another adapter with which I have been charging before. All cables are new and chargers are perfect. Also tried different wall sockets in the house and tried all ports on the Mac.

Comment: That's what I wanted to confirm.  The next thing is to plug into an external monitor.  If you get nothing, you'll have to take it in for service.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the touchID button down on the device for about 10 seconds to hard reboot the device. It may be hung but this should force reset your laptop.

If this does not work then there is something malfunctioning and you need to bring it to Apple. You're close to the end of your warranty period so they may give you some leeway in repairing it under warranty.